Freeform form flagging inputs as required, even though thery have data within
I've created a freeform form the manual way, as I need control over the form and layout in a bespoke way. On submitting the form it flags errors and the error text says the field are required. Even though the input elements where filled.
Also noticed that I have to refresh the screen a few times in the CP to show recent changes and field additions, which seems weird.
Has anyone seen this before. I've madea support ticket, but I'm being impatient while they get back to me, in the hope someone can offer some light on the situation.
The form can be found at mevkitcars.co.uk/order-form. The files in the freeform plugin are set to required, as I assumed they would have to sync up. The manual input fields also 'required' declared on them in the html template.
All help greatly appreciated.
Ian

Upon reviewing your form source code, I can see that some of the fields are missing the name attribute. This would be enough to cause this issue.
For example, you have:
<input type="email" class="email-field" placeholder="you@youremail.com" required="" value="" autocomplete="email" id="email">
But it should be:
<input type="email" name="email" class="email-field" placeholder="you@youremail.com" required="" value="" autocomplete="email" id="email">
The Postcode field might be named incorrectly. I see this in the code:
<input type="text" class="postcode-field" placeholder="Postcode" name="post-code" value="" id="postcode" required="" autocomplete="postal-code">
But perhaps the field name is actually post_code, not post-code? :)
